# Regex for JkUnMount in Apache configuration file

Tags: regex, apache, tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-jk

For example I have REST Api base path: `/rest-api/api/`

There are many APIs under it (e.g. `/rest-api/api/groups`, `/rest-api/api/groups/users`, `/rest-api/api/teams`, `/rest-api/api/games`, etc.)

Now I want to unmount all the paths except ones starting with `/rest-api/api/groups`.

I tried to write JKUnMount `/rest-api/api/(?!groups).*` but it does not work.

I also tried with LocationMatch, but it did not work too.

Is there an option that regex for my apache configuration is disabled? Or maybe I do smth wrong?

Comment: `(?!groups)*` is doing no meaningless job here, it is something you required to be missing optionally. Your regex is equal to `/rest-api/api/`

Comment: Agree with @WiktorStribiżew. Did you try just removing the star?

Comment: Please use https://www.regex101.com to play around with your patters and check which one works for you.

Comment: @PJProudhon No actually I want to exclude all starting with /rest-api/api/groups. I will update the question now. And I cannot make it work with any regex style :\

Comment: @Mandy8055 I have tried with regex101.com, and /rest-api/api/(?!groups).* works quite good, but does not work with apache configuration.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew /rest-api/api/ will unmount all the paths under it.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I said.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But I do not want to unmount all the paths. I need /rest-api/api/groups and all other APIs under it to be mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding:

```
JKUnMount /rest-api/api/* worker
<LocationMatch "/rest-api/api/groups/*">
   SetHandler jakarta-servlet
   SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME worker
</LocationMatch>
```